# 「わからない事は聞くのよ」What makes this imperative?

Tags: usage, sentence-final-particles, imperatives

This is used in an imperative sense: "If there's anything you don't understand, just ask."

I wanted to know how the particles worked to give this tone, since, without the particles, it could've been a general sentence saying "I/you/we ask things I/you/we don't understand."

Comment: This の after the 聞く is the key here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it may look like an imperative ***in that translation***, it would not be expressly called "imperative" among us native speakers.  It is only "imperative-ish" at best.

「のよ」 makes a phrase a soft-sounding and mostly-feminine way to remind the listener of the need to perform a certain action (as in a good piece of advice).

「わからない事は聞く**のよ**。」: mostly feminine

「わからない事は聞く**んだよ**。」: largely but not entirely masculine